# how to pad cursor in input field in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

I have a cursor and hint that insists on being flush to the top left of an input field and I was wondering how I can fix this typically.[image: an]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it in the center set gravity as the center in XML.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center it, you can use the property gravity as Ashi Agarwal said. But you need to center it vertically:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```